# DataGridViewColumn with ContextMenuStrip - How can I *always* get the associated cell/row?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a DataGridViewColumn with a ContextMenuStrip assigned in the designer.  In the handler for the menu strip item's click event, I need to get the row index of the row containing the cell that spawned the context menu.  `DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex` works fine as long as the cell was selected with a left-click before the context menu is shown.  However, when right-clicking the cell without selected it first, the `RowIndex` is always 0.  I've tried finding the parent of the context menu strip item and working up the chain to the cell/column, but `ContextMenuStrip.Parent` is always null.  Is there a way that I can do this without using the menu's location?  If I have to use location, is there a fool-proof way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A right-mouse click isn't the only way to invoke a context menu. Shift+F10 or the Context Menu Key will also invoke it. Invoking a context menu from the keyboard doesn't give an X, Y coordinate, so the only way to know what the context of the menu should be is the concept of "currently selected item".

What I do is override the MouseDown event and if the right-button is pressed, select the cell under the mouse.

Comment: Oooooh, good idea!  I'm going to try it and will let you know.

Comment: I ended up having to set the DataGridView's CurrentCell property on the right-mouse click, as opposed to selecting the cell.  But the handling mouse-down and setting this works perfectly.  Thanks!